# Apache Nifi for data masking

Tags: apache-nifi, data-masking

We are using Nifi as our main data ingestion engine. Nifi is used to ingest data from multiple sources like DB, blob storage, etc and all of the data is pushed to kafka ( with avro as serializatiton format). Now, one of the requirement is to mask the specific fields(
PII) in input data.

1. Is nifi a good tool to do that ?
2. Does it have any processor to support data masking/obfuscation ?

Answer (score 1):

Nifi comes with the `EncryptContent` and `CryptographicHashContent` and `CryptographicHashAttribute` processors which can be used to encrypt/hash data respectively.

I would look into this first.

In addition `ReplaceText` could also do simple masking. An `ExecuteScript` processor could perform custom masking, or a combination of `UpdateRecord` with a `ScriptedRecordSetWriter` could easily mask certain fields in a record.